# "Could not install package 'Sandboxable.Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage 1.1.0'"

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have created a portable cross platform project. I want to add reference to `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage`.

When I am trying to install `Sandboxable.Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage` 1.1.0 through *package manager console* I am getting the error:

> Install-Package : Could not install package 'Sandboxable.Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage 1.1.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 
>   'MonoAndroid,Version=v6.0', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework.

But when I am trying to install through *manage NuGet package for solution* I am getting the error:

> Could not install package 'Sandboxable.Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage 1.1.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile111', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: that package doesn't appear to support Xamarin Android

Comment: Can you please help me to know which package support xamarin android for accessing windows azure blob storage for PCL

Comment: google "xamarin azure blob" and read the first hit

Comment: Thakn you Jason for your lead.                                                                    I have installedthe WindowsAzure.Storage-4.4.0(preview) and solution has compiled successfully.